# How to deselect an item in a jList after a certain ammount of milliseconds on a mouseExit event

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlist, listselectionlistener

I have a jList called `todoList`

When the user click on an item in the list, it stays selected. But I would like the currently selected item in the list to deselect "by itself" after 400 milliseconds when the mouse exits the jList.

This must only run if there is something already selected in the list.

I am using Netbeans IDE and this is what is have tried so far:

```
private void todoListMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if (!todoList.isSelectionEmpty()) {
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        try {
            thread.wait(400L);
            todoList.clearSelection();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
 private void todoListMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if (!todoList.isSelectionEmpty()) {
        Thread thread= Thread.currentThread();
        try {
            thread.wait(400L);
            todoList.clearSelection();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

These both just make everything stop working.

My though process was that i need to create a new Thread that will wait for 400 milliseconds and then run the clearSelection() method of the jList. This would happen every time the mouse exits the list and run only if there is something in the list that is already selected.

I hope I am explaining my problem thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Object#wait` is waiting(rather than *sleeping*) to be notified but this is not happening. Instead the timeout causing an `InterruptedException` bypassing the call to `clearSelection`.

Don't use raw `Threads` in `Swing` applications. Instead use a `Swing Timer` which was designed to interact with Swing components.

```
if (!todoList.isSelectionEmpty()) {
   Timer timer = new Timer(400, new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         todoList.clearSelection();
      }
   });
   timer.setRepeats(false);
   timer.start();
}
```

Comment: Note that the copied code from me does not work, I forgot to add `.start()` and some other things ;)

Comment: Thank you. Fix the compiling error (see rev history), so it is correct. +1 after edit.

Comment: I have used this and it works, but not perfectly. When i click the item on the list and my mouse exits the list, the item deselects as it should, but then when i try to click the item again, it does not even select. I think it's because the timer is not stopped after the 400ms and so the `ActionListener` gets messed up. I used `System.out.println(e);` within the `public void actionPerformed` and the output was `java.awt.event.ActionEvent[unknown type,cmd=null,when=1365513320800,modifiers=] on javax.swing.Timer@aba647`. Can you help me once again?

Comment: i cant up vote because i need 15 points :( otherwise i would have!

Comment: @Reimeus I'm sorry i just have one last question.

Is there a way to stop the timer when the mouse **enters** the list? I dont want the item to deselect if the mouse is within the list.

Comment: That is a different matter. Hint: define the Timer outside the scope of the `ActionListener`. Make an attempt at doing this and post a new question if you get stuck. Good luck!

Comment: @Reimeus Hey can you check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992196/how-to-start-a-timer-on-a-mouse-exit-event-and-stop-that-same-timer-on-a-mouse-e

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are blocking the AWT-Event-Thread.

The solution is to use a [swing timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html):

```
private void todoListMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{
   if (!todoList.isSelectionEmpty()) {
        new Timer(400, new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                  todoList.clearSelection();
              }
        }).start();
    }
}
```