# How to start a Timer on a mouse exit event and stop that same Timer on a mouse enter event?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlist

I have a list called `reminderList`.

When the mouse clicks on an item in the list and the mouse exits the list, i want a timer to start.

When the mouse enters the list, i want that timer to stop, if it is still running.

When the mouse exits the list again, i want that same timer to restart.

```
public void waitReminderList(int status) {
    Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            reminderList.clearSelection();
            dismissReminder.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    if (status == 0) {
        if (!reminderList.isSelectionEmpty()) {
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.restart();
            timer.start();
        }
    } else if (status == 1) {
        if (!reminderList.isSelectionEmpty()) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

private void reminderListMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    waitReminderList(0);
} 

private void reminderListMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    waitReminderList(1);
}
```

The problem is: the timer doesn't stop or restart or do anything after it has been started but i need it to.

My solution to the problem was to have an int and then i can control what i want the timer to do by the value of the int. But it didn't work, the timer doesn't stop...

So what am i doing wrong?

I know there have been other questions like this but, i am still fairly new to java and i do not understand the answers given.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried adding some debug output with `System.out.println()` inside if-blocks, to see what code it is reaching when you do certain things?

Comment: I did, but i took them out when i posted this. They didn't help me, i only saw that my if statements were working. But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't keep creating a new Timer in your waitReminderList() method. You should define the Timer as a class variable.

Then you just stop/start it as required.

Comment: It worked, thanks! It makes so much sense now, i wish i thought of it before i posted...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are creating a new `Timer` every time `waitReminderList` is called. Any previous running `Timer` objects will not be stopped. Since you want a single `Timer` move the reference *outside* the method, e.g. at class level.